# stuck on integrating fractions for ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy+3x-y-3}{xy-2x+4y-8}$
I factored it $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x-1)(y+3)}{(x+4)(y-2)}$
I used separation of variables $\int \frac{y-2}{y+3} dy = \int \frac{x-1}{x+4} dx$
I got stuck.
Is the next step to rewrite the fractions as $\int \frac{y}{y+3} dy - \int \frac{2}{y+3} dy = \int \frac{x}{x+4} - \int \frac{1}{x+4}dx$
I tried integration by parts and it didn't help.

Comment: Note that $y-2$ seems to have become $y+2$ while you were looking the other way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm fixed typo :)

Comment: both integrands are improper fractions. do the long division to write them as a constant and proper fraction. it would then be easier to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

A better rewriting would be, e.g., $\frac{x-1}{x+4}=\frac{x+4}{x+4}-\frac{5}{x+4}$.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that technique. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @Celeritas: You can view it either as an instance of [long polynomial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) (as abel suggests in a comment to the question), or as a disguised way to substitute $u=x+4$ so the denominator becomes a variable (as HDE's answer suggests). In the latter case $\frac{x-1}{x+4}$ becomes $\frac{u-5}{u} = 1-\frac{5}{u}$.

Comment: Is it synthetic division or is that different?

Comment: @Celeritas: I've never heard that term, but Wikipedia says it's a method for doing polynomial division that applies in this case, so yes.

Comment: In general you can't apply synthetic division (Ruffini's rule). For example if the denominator is $x^2+9.$ But in this case you can use Ruffini's rule to get the quotient and the remainder.

Comment: Ok so I'll read up on long polynomial division.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For the left side:
$$u=y+3 \to y-2=u-?$$

For the right side:
$$v=x+4 \to x-1=v+?$$

For the first instance, you will have
$$\frac{u-a}{u}=1-\frac{a}{u}$$

For the second instance, you will have something similar. Can you go from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You arrive at $$\int \frac{y+2}{y+3} dy = \int \frac{x-1}{x+4} dx.$$ Now, note that

$$\frac{y+2}{y+3}=\frac{y+3-1}{y+3}=1-\frac{1}{y+3}$$ and

$$\frac{x-1}{x+4}=\frac{x+4-5}{x+4}=1-\frac{5}{x+4}.$$

Comment: What is it called when you rewrite a fraction like that i.e. add to the numerator so that part of it goes to 1 when divided by the denominator?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. But in this case it is a quick way to make the division.

Comment: @Celeritas, it is called called division. look up proper and improper rational functions.